# If The cell has values, select the same quantity of lines in another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In my first sheet I insert 389 lines of text, it makes a process and appears in sheet 3 fully processed, but I need to select the same number of lines in the Sheet 3, then copy it.

The main problem is that the quantity of lines that I insert in the first sheet can be from 1 to 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inputing your data such that each line is filled from the first line down to some line you can find the last row number with the following, where "A" is the column the data is in.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Then you can go through the data with a loop like:

```
For each cell in sht.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
    'do something with cell
next cell
```